# .net core - Middleware don't handle requests

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am having a problem with middleware in .Net Core 2. Middleware doesn't handle any coming requests.
What I have implemented.

KeyValidatorMiddleware class:

```
public class KeyValidatorMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public KeyValidatorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("api-key"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("No API key found !");
            return;
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

and in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
    app.UseMiddleware<KeyValidatorMiddleware>();
}
```

And nothing works, What am i missing in order to make the middleware work?

Comment: Where in the pipeline have you added the `UseMiddleware` line? Can you show us a more complete `Configure` method?

Comment: Move the `UseMiddleware` line to be nearer the top, middleware runs in order and it may stop at the MVC level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should move the `UseMiddleware` line to be nearer the top, middleware runs in order and it may stop at the MVC level.

For example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseMiddleware<KeyValidatorMiddleware>();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
}
```

Comment: OP: It's a slight aside, but you're also going to want to reconsider where `app.UseCors` goes based on this information (and `app.UseHttpsRedirection` actually).

Answer (score 3):

Registration of middleware is ordered. So anything you register before MVC will run before MVC.

MVC handles the request if it matches a URL that MVC can handle. Anything you register after MVC will only handle the request if MVC fails to match the URL.